# blow up of a log resolution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose that $(X, \omega)$ is a Kähler manifold with a semi-ample canonical line bundle(meaning there exists $m$ such that $mK_{X}$ is base point free). Then we have a canonical map $\Phi: X \to \mathbb P^{N}$ where $N$ is the Kodaira dimension of $X$. It is well know that $\Phi(X)$ is a normal projective algebraic variety. One major tool one invokes in such a situation is to take a resolution of singularity $\Phi': X' \to \Phi(X)$ such that the exceptional locus of $\Phi'$ is a simple normal crossing, and $X'$ is smooth. My understanding is that one thing that is nice about this is when one pulls back the the restriction of the Fubini-Study metric from $\Phi(X)$ to $X'$, it is going to be singular(meaning zero somewhere), but the singularity will not be too bad, and it is always big so that one can use the Kodaira lemma.

However, I read from the paper: [Riemannian geometry of the Kähler currents](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0445.pdf), page 35, section 4.5 not only does the author take a resolution of singularity, but he also blows up at a point on the smooth part of the divisor of the resolution. What is the purpose of this operation?

Comment: It seems that they are trying to get a precise understanding of the geometry near a particular point (which is produced in Lemma 4.8, which is called in Theorem 4.1) and blowing up a point is often a useful tool to understand what's going on near it.